# Links not working in Azure DevOps Code Coverage Tab Using Istanbul

Tags: azure-devops, istanbul

I've got [Istanbul Code Coverage](https://istanbul.js.org/) working on my Azure DevOps pipeline.  The first page loads fine and I can drill into file but when I try to drill into the covered file:

[image]

I get the following error on Azure DevOps Code Coverage tab (it works fine locally)

> Blocked script execution in 'chrome-error://chromewebdata/' because the document's frame is sandboxed and the 'allow-scripts' permission is not set.

The files are generated by the Istanbul tool, so I don't know how to set allow-scripts permissions.

Another issue is that the 'All Files' link returns a 404.

How do I fix these issues?

Comment: how is this related to ADO? fix your chrome

Comment: I found the same [issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/issues/3027) on the github.  You could have a try to use the [solutions](https://davidsekar.com/aspnetcore/code-coverage-html-reports-are-missing-styles-in-vsts) discussed on the github as a workaround.